# SQL Server data import dilemma

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created an application that will be importing CSV files into a database table, and I've got multiple CSV files I need to import into a table in a SQL Server database.

I've got a couple approaches in mind but I'm not sure which is most practical. The application works by asking the user to select the files they want to import (from their local file system) and then they simply click a `[Load Files]` button. These files may contain 100,000+ rows at times.

What would be better for the above scenario?

1. Import CSV file into datatable using C# and open-source [GenericParser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) then using a traditional method of BulkCopy to push the datatable to the database

   **Note**: my concern is the strain on users PC when doing this for files with 100,000+ rows. How will this affect the processing or would it crash the program?
2. Use Bulk Insert which requires the file name and path. My concern for this option is I'm not sure if the server would be able to process the Bulk Insert command without the physical file being located on the server? The file path would relate to the users local machine. The only time I've used Bulk Insert is when I was logged onto the server itself, which is not possible for this app.
3. Is there a way to do it with Linq? While I'm not really familiar with Linq if it can be accomplished I'm open to trying it.

Any insight is appreciated. I know what I need to do just not sure of how to accomplish it practically.

Thanks

Comment: Notice that for Bulk Insert the 'LOAD DATA INFILE' command in MySQL has a --local option [check reference documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) "The --local option causes mysqlimport to read data files from the client host"

Comment: @AdolfoPerez Thanks for the tip...MySQL is my next database to conquer for this dataload app. Saved me another question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class in .NET.  It will allow you to import rows almost as fast at the BULK INSERT statement, but only requires that you populate a DataTable with the rows, and then send them to SQL Server.

Another consideration you might want to look at would be (and this is my personal favorite for simple file import programs) to use PowerShell instead of C#, which has a [built-in cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) for imporing CSV files.  Pretty cool stuff.

Comment: How does SQLBulkCopy perform whenever there are 100,000-200,000 rows?Powershell may not be available on all machines that this app would be used on. It's a portable/lightweight application.

Comment: Rows don't matter.  Bytes matter.  1,000,000 rows that are 1 byte wide will take far less time to import than a table with 100 rows each of 1 megabyte.  The performance of SQLBulkCopy has been fine for me in these use cases.  If you want more details, check out Alberto's study of it: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2009/11/30/sqlbulkcopy-performance-analysis.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dave. Got it to work just fine and performance appears to be acceptable. Running the bulk copy on seperate thread than main application, of course.

Answer (score 0):

1) loader app in .Net is a good choice, generally. 100,000 rows is really not a strenuous workload, especially for simple loads. Only if there is a ton of multiple-table-joins involved in order to look up values on the fly would that really be a big concern.

2) although strictly speaking physical file location is just a performance question, I wouldn't do it. It will introduce administrative headaches.

3) I don't have experience with Linq, I cannot remark.

Just for bonus alternate idea: if you have IIS running somewhere, maybe even on the DB server, you can whip up a lightweight, one-page "webapp" which is just a CGI script with ODBC connection to the DB and the user just feeds the CSV in as a "web/CGI" upload. No utility application to install on user workstations this way.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you have to see on in two basic views:

1. Do you need make some operations with data before insert in into database (some sumarization, correction,...)?
   If yes, than here is the best way to upload rows from file to object (each row into one object instance). And than you can elegantly move with list of items with Linq.
2. Do you need only insert rows from file to database as they are?
   I this case, use process described in point 2 of your question.

I'd prefer to upload file to server before any action. It's more safe.

Comment: Uploading file to a server isn't an option. This must be a portable standalone solution that won't necesarrily give user's rights to a specific server. There will be multiple servers that must be updated. Uploading file would require domain permissions, which may not always be the case. However, database access is never an issue.